# checking for existance of ";C:\Python27" before appending ";C:\Python27" to environment variable PATH

Tags: path, append, environment-variables

I am using following code to append ";C:\Python27" to environment variable PATH..

```
@echo off

Setx Path "%PATH%;C:\Python27" -M

PAUSE
```

but if i run this batch file more than once, it is appending ";C:\Python27" many times that should not happen.
SO i  have to check for ;C:\Python27 before appending it to PATH variable.

Is there any command for this purpose?

Answer (score 0):

The following Powershell should do it:

```
$needPython = $env:path | select-string -NotMatch -SimpleMatch "c:\python27"
if ($needPython) {
    [Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("tstpath", $env:path + ";c:\python27", "User")
}
```

You can change `User` to `Machine` or `Process` to set a machine or process level environment variable.

You can run this directly from a powershell prompt.

If you're running this from a dos command line use (you need the full path to your script or `.\` if it's in the current directory):

```
powershell "& '.\myscript.ps1'"
```